# System.IO.FileNotFoundExecption, even when file is present

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am uploading files using GUID for their names and then I am trying to download them but I am getting a file not found error even when file is there on the server,I think, I am doing something wrong with command arguement but I am not sure what. Please tell me where I am wrong, any help is appreciated.

Database schema:
 I have 2 columns : ReceiptFileName - Stores filename without GUID for UI.
                    filename - Stores filename with GUID.

Aspx code:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("filename") %>' Text='<%# Bind("ReceiptFileName") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code for Upload:

```
{
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            //check file Extension & Size
            string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
            {
                filename = filename + Guid.NewGuid();
            }
            int filesize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            if (filesize > (20 * 1024))
            {
                Label1.Text = "Please upload a zip or a pdf file";
            }

            string fileextention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
            if (fileextention.ToLower() != ".zip" && fileextention.ToLower() != ".pdf")
            {
                Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                Label1.Text = "Please upload a zip or a pdf file";

            }



            else
            {
                //string ReceiptFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string ReceiptFileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);

                //save file to disk

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Reciepts/" + ReceiptFileName));
}
```

Code For Downlaod:

```
protected void gridExpenditures_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "FileName=" + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Reimbursement/Reciepts/") + e.CommandArgument);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some example filenames with full path that your system has generated?

Comment: Did you step through the code and verify the full path to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be just silly but I can only read the file paths are different:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Reciepts/" + ReceiptFileName));
```

Vs:

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Reimbursement/Reciepts/")
```

The last path has `Reimbursement` in it. The first doesn't.

Comment: No I tried doing that it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: I think it has something to do with GUID and command arguement becuase when I didn't use GUID to code and database files where uploading and downloading perfectly.

Comment: If you set a debugger on both lines, what is the file path for both then?

Comment: In both cases filepath is /Reimbursement/Reciepts/...then my filename

Comment: Can you past both file names please?